# How do we get price data from chart Trading View?

Tags: reactjs, charts, trading, tradingview-api

I'd like to get price data and date from the chart Trading View using React.js so that I can use the data in my application (e.g. Exchange (buy/sell)).

Answer (score 0):

I found a chart called Lightweight TradingView and it works great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).